# Android: How to send location information to server while app is inactive

Tags: android, design-patterns

What is the appropriate way to implement a location-based Android app that periodically sends its location to a server?

Here is the specific flow I would like to implement:

1. Main Android app is inactive (i.e., hasn't been launched)
2. Based on GPS location of the device, the server may push a message (via C2DM) to the device
3. Upon receiving the message, a notification should appear in the notification bar (which can then be used to launch the app)

My main confusion stems from point #1: how do I send GPS coordinates to the server if the app has not been launched?  Is it simply a matter of implementing a service that periodically sends the phone location to the server?  How can I ensure the service is always running once the user has installed the app?

(The Groupon app for Android does something similar, where you intermittently receive notifications of nearby deals even when the app is inactive.  Any idea how they may have implemented this?)

Comment: Please check this out ,much similar app and is working fine but i need some help regarding some features which you will know after reading my post , and sorry for putting this thing in answer as i can,t find the option of comment.
.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088095/how-can-i-send-the-gps-and-network-location-cordinates-to-a-server-static-ip/14103445#14103445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use just a `Service`, Better set an Alarm using `AlarmManager` each (5 minutes, 15 minutes or what you need) and then get the location. @CommonsWare have done some [code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) thats quite useful ( it deals also with `WEAK_LOCKS` so if the phone goes sleep everything still run etc..)

Also, You don't need to use C2DM because you must send your location to the server and the server response you with the geo-information. C2DM is only for the case that you not start the communication.

Answer (score 0):

You, can simply create a background service then implements a location listener. In that location listener, you can set the time interval in the `requestLocationUpdate` method to ping the GPS at particular time intervals. 
Here is a location manager instance:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, timeinterval2, 0, locationListener);
```

You can send that location to the server from the service. You can also  send notifications to launch the app.