# How can I send the GPS and Network location cordinates to a server (static IP)?

Tags: android, gps, send

I am a beginner in the Android Development.I want to make an android app which sends the GPS and network locations (lat & long) to my server (static IP).
I have found the following code and it worked successfully, data receive at the app which is already made at server side (Right now it has nothing to do with client app)

Data received at my Server when I click the button 'Send Location' on my Android App.

- GET /31.4244456/74.7349772 HTTP/1.1
- Host: 180.178.169.77:6081
- Connection: keep-Alive
- User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/Unavailable (java 1.4)

180.178.169.77 is my server IP and 6081 is the port

At this point everything is going fine and I acheived almost what I wanted but the real problem I'm facing is that my Android app hangs and crash after sending this data to server. Please resolve my problem if anybody has an idea.

I have found the Code from here.
http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/how-to-get-the-current-location-address-and-send-it-to-a-server-on-android#.UNLbTOT0Dxo

Here is my AddressActivity.java

```
package com.gideon.address;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AddressActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String lat="", lon="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) AddressActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoc);
                    tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });

    Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postData(lat, lon);
        }
    });

    Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddress);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            tv.setText(GetAddress(lat, lon));
        }
    });

}

public void postData(String la, String lo) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("http://myappurl.com/Home/Book/"+la+"/"+lo);
    HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("http://180.178.169.77:6081/"+la+"/"+lo);

    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
        String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
    }
} 
public String GetAddress(String lat, String lon)
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String ret = "";
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon), 1);
        if(addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
        }
        else{
            ret = "No Address returned!";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = "Can't get Address!";
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gideon.address"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AddressActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `postData` off the main thread to a secondary thread. Look at `Async` task for examples here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have seen the link but as i told m a beginner so can you please explain me where and how i modify my code to resolve my problem?? or can you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            postData(lat, lon);
        }
```

runs on the UI thread. It means that while you do the "post" action, the UI isn't refreshed and cannot be accessed - your app get stuck until the post ends.

You need to do something like:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        PostAsyncTask postAsyncTask = new PostAsyncTask();
        postAsyncTask.execute();
    }



 private class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     postData(lat, lon);
     return 0;
 }

 protected void onPreExecute() {
     // show progress dialog
 }


     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         // hide  progress dialog
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ,let me try this and then i will let you know if it works :)

Comment: Can you please guide me what should i remove from my code and where exactly i should add the above code into my Addressactivity.java ??  because when i add the above code into my main app code it give me many errors.please help me.Thanks

Comment: Add PostAsyncTask class somewhere inside AddressActivity class and replace btnSend OnClickListener onClick(View v) with the onClick(View v) I posted. I Strongly suggest you read Android AsyncTask documentation as Slartibartfast suggested.

Comment: I tried its giving error, please add your code into main app code and post it in the answers, then i will give it try. Hope this will resolve my issue.

Comment: placing the post action in a background thread is the first step. now remove the Toast.makeText from postData(String la, String lo) - because the toast should run on the UI. use e.printStackTrace(); instead. use the debugger to see exacty where your app crash, edit your question and write the exact error you got.

Comment: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/Unavailable (java 1.4)                what that means ? in the data i receive at my server??

Comment: what if i want to bypass the 'send location' button and want my client app to automatically send the locations to server after a predefined time interval or when the location changes,what should i do for that?